# status code initialization value for a rest API

Tags: rest, http-status-codes

For my application, I am initializing status code with `200` and then at different stages of computation, I am changing the status code.

Is this the best practice? Or should I initialize with let's say `400` and then in the end change it to 200 if everything is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on your programming style but in most cases I follow the *happy* path and in case of an error/exception I return immediately a 400/500 response. If no errors occur then I return a 200 response.

Anyway, this question is not specific to `REST API` and it really depends on the programming language and/or developer style.

Comment: Yes, it might not be specific to rest api style but is relevant to most of us out there.. both of the approaches have their pros and cons and there should be a standard way to decide the better approach